# Проблема с машиной состояний aiogram

Tags: aiogram

Мне нужно в одной из стадий принять от пользователя фотографию (не фото профиля, просто фотку, которую он отправит) и сохранить её id, но при отправке фотографии боту, он просто никак не реагирует на неё

Код для примера:

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup


class UserState(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    photo = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['reg'])
async def user_register(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите своё имя")
    await UserState.name.set()

  
@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.name)
async def get_username(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(username=message.text)
    await message.answer("Отлично! Теперь Отправте фото")
    await UserState.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=UserState.photo)
async def get_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    print(message.content_type) #text но только когда это текст, если фото, ничего не происходит
    # код дальше ещё не написан
    await state.finish()
```

ещё я думал сделать так:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Add_ad.waiting_for_picture, content_types = ['photo'])
async def name_entered(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    print(message.content_type) # photo
    await state.finish()
```

тогда всё работает нормально, как должно, но текст будет полностью игнорироваться и нельзя его отловить и написать типо "пришлите фотографию"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно в одном хендлере "ловить" разные типы сообщений, то можно указать нужное Вам, в виде списка типов:

```
content_types=['photo', 'text']
```

Получить id фотографии (картинки) можно следующим образом:

```
photo_id = message.photo[0].file_id
```

Вообще, для удобства и лучшего понимания можно вывести само сообщение, которое поймал хендлер, обычным print-ом. Там много интересного можно увидеть.

Ну и, если нужно, чтобы хендлер реагировал по разному, на разные типы сообщения, можно задать условия.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'text'], state='нужное состояние')
async def get_photo_text(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext)
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        "запускаем код, сохраняем id и т. д."
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Прикольная фотка')
    elif message.content_type == 'text':
        'выполняем другой код'
    await state.finish()
```

Вся необходимая информация есть в документации, хотя пользоваться ей, это отдельный навык). Я вот пока скилл не набил.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods

Надеюсь что дал тот ответ, который был нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы мне очень помоги))

Comment: @Goxa, если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, как верный=)